# Automatic text size scaling by dimension's value

Tags: java, android, resources, dimensions

I have set of dimension files like:

\res\values-normal-xxhdpi\dimens.xtml

```
<!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
<string name="dimention_id">normal-xxhdpi</string>
<dimen name="activity_margin">8dp</dimen>
<dimen name="big_text_size">8sp</dimen> 
<dimen name="mid_text_size">5sp</dimen> 
<dimen name="small_text_size">3sp</dimen>
<dimen name="logo_size">100dp</dimen>
<dimen name="button_height">55dp</dimen>
<dimen name="button_width">200dp</dimen>
<dimen name="panel_counter_width">190dp</dimen>
```

When I loading this dimensions by `Context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.mid_text_size)` I receive "mid_text_size" is equal to 20.

I sure that it is correct file because changing of value 5 to other value will appear changes in the application.

Why it scaling up to 20 from 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of the function [Resources.getDimenstion(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDimension(int)) states:

> Resource dimension value multiplied by the appropriate metric.

So probably, if you check [DisplayMetrics.scaledDensity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#scaledDensity) it would show the value of 4.

Remember that `sp` is a relative value, that is supposed to assure, that the font looks much like the same on all screen sizes and dimesions and resolutions.

I suggest you reading the theory of [units used in Android environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-on-android)

Comment: Yes it solves my problem.

float dimension = getContext().getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.mid_text_size);

DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

float scale_index = metrics.scaledDensity;

dimension = dimension / scale_index;

Interesting that when we set dimention value in layout it working simple for every avalable layout file. But when we using getDimentions() function we must test metrics.scaledDensity value. Thank you.